# Duda de "for" en python

Tags: python

Estoy empezando a programar con lenguaje de python, y uno de mis ejercicios es realizar el numero factorial de un numero n 
este es mi código:

```
result=1
n=input("Deme un numero \n")
for i in range (1,n):
   result=result*i
print(result)
```

mi duda es como escribo el rango de for en la parte de (1,**n**)
si 'n' es al numero que debo llegar o detenerse el for

Comment: Cambia `n` por `n+1`, ya que la función `range(X)` itera hasta el valor `X-1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Justamente, como dice el comentario tienes que cambiar a n por n+1, ya que el for lo que hace es hacer desde 1 hasta n-1, cuando i vale n, ya el código dentro del bucle no se ejecuta.

```
result=1
n=int(input("Deme un numero \n"))
for i in range (1,(n+1)):
   result=result*i
print(result)
```

Comment: ok gracias, también ya encontré el otro error que tenia

Answer (score 1):

Como te han comentado, el bucle for se detiene en el último valor del rango sin incluirlo, por lo que deberías incrementar el límite superior del rango.

Otra opción es hacer que el bucle vaya al revés, es decir, desde n hasta 1. De esa forma el número que se queda fuera del bucle sería el 1 lo cual no tendría efecto en el cálculo del factorial.

```
 for i in range (n,1):
```